# Let $\omega=\frac{\sqrt{3}i-1}{2}$. Prove $\frac{\omega a-\omega}{1+a+\omega}\in\Bbb{R}$ for all $a\in\Bbb C$ with $|a|=1$, $a\not=\omega^2$.

Tags: complex-numbers

> $\newcommand{\i}{\mathrm i}$Let $\omega=\frac{\sqrt3\i-1}2$, and $a\in\Bbb C$ with $|a|=1$, $a\not=\omega^2$. Prove that $z=\dfrac{\omega a-\omega}{1+a+\omega}\in\Bbb R$.

There's an obvious bash: let $a=\cos x+\i\sin x$. So
\[\frac{\omega a-\omega}{1+a+\omega}=\frac{2\cos x-2\sqrt3\sin x-2}{2\cos x+2\sqrt3\sin x+4}\in\mathbb R.\]
But can we solve it by the properties of complex numbers?

For example, prove $z=\overline z$. But I got a strange result when computing this.

Comment: The reason for writing $a$ as $\cos x+\i\sin x$ is because it enables us to expand the quotient. And it should be $z=\overline z$, which is $\iff z\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: I suspect it helps a lot to notice that $\omega^2=\omega^{-1}=\overline{\omega}$ and $a^{-1} = \overline a$.

Comment: I see. I made a mistake in my previous comment, which I deleted. I apologize for any confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $w=e^{\frac{2\pi }3i}$ is a cube root of unity. So we have $1+w+w^2=0$ and $z=\dfrac{\omega(a-1)}{a-\omega^2}$.

##### Show $z=\overline z$, as expected by OP

We have $\omega\overline\omega=1$ as well as $a\overline a = |a|^2=1$.
$$\overline z=\frac{\overline\omega(\overline a-1)}{\overline a-{\overline\omega}^2}=\frac{\omega^2a\,\overline\omega(\overline a-1)}{\omega^2a(\overline a-{\overline\omega}^2)}=\dfrac{\omega(1-a)}{\omega^2-a}=z$$

##### Another approach, compute the argument of $z$

$$\arg(p+q)=\frac{\arg(p)+\arg(q)}2\pmod{2\pi}$$ for all complex number $p$ and $q$ with $|p|=|q|$ and none of $p,q,p+q$ is $0$. This formula can be seen immediately by the geometric interpretation of complex numbers. Note that $|a|=|{-}1|=|{-}w^2|=1$. There are two cases.

- $a=1$.
  Then $z=0$ is real.
- $a\not=1$.
  $$\begin{aligned}
  \arg(z)&=\arg(w)+\arg(a+(-1))-\arg(a+(-w^2))\\
  &=\frac{2\pi}3+\frac{\arg a +\pi}2 - \frac{\arg a+\frac\pi3}2\\
  &=\pi \pmod{2\pi}
  \end{aligned}$$
  Hence, $z$ is a negative number.

Comment: Nit pick: $a$ cannot be $1$ in the second approach, and accordingly $p,q,p+q\neq 0$.

Comment: @durianice Thanks. Moreover, $a$ cannot be $\omega^2$, which is a condition in the question. I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The conjugate of the denominator is $1+a^{-1}+\omega^{-1}$, since inverses and conjugates are the same thing for elements of the unit circle.

It suffices to show $(\omega a-\omega)(1+a^{-1}+\omega^{-1})$ is real. This evaluates to: $$(a-1)+\omega(a-1)+\omega(1-a^{-1})=a-1+\omega(a-a^{-1})$$Which is real if and only if the imaginary part is zero, if and only if: $$0=\Im a+\frac{-1}{2}(\Im(a)-(-\Im(a)))+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(\Re(a)-\Re(a))$$

Which is true.

Answer (score 1):

We know that a Mobius transformation $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ sends circles/lines to circles/lines and it is enough to check $3$ values to determine the image of a circle/line.

Consider the Mobius transformation $f(z)=\frac{wz-w}{z+w+1}$ where $w=-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$. Then:

1. $f(1)=0\in\Bbb R$
2. $f(-1)=-2\in\Bbb R$ and
3. $f(i)=-\frac{3+2\sqrt3}{4+2\sqrt3}\in\Bbb R.$

Therefore, if $a\in\{z\in\Bbb C\,\,|\,\,\,|z|=1\}$ then $f(a)\in\Bbb R.$

Comment: Honestly, I can't substitute $i$ successfully but youthcando.

Comment: The third easy case, $f(\omega^2)=\infty$.

Comment: It might be better to write extended lines instead of lines and $\Bbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ Instead of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to write $ a = cosx + isinx$ is an inherent property of complex numbers.

If this doesn't feel "complex" enough, remember that there is a bijection

$$F : [0, \infty[ \times [0, 2\pi[ \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, (r, \phi) \mapsto re^{i\phi}=rcos\phi + i r sin\phi$$

which you are basically using to evaluate your a. Because $\vert a \vert = 1$, $r=1$ therefore you can write a is you have done. So you're using indeed properties of complex numbers.

Comment: You have a good point. Actually I wanted to mean properties of operation, if you can understand it...

Answer (score 0):

To show $\newcommand{\w}{\omega}\newcommand{\ww}{\bar{\omega}}\newcommand{\aa}{\bar{a}}$
$$
\frac{\w a - \w}{1+a+\w} = \frac{\ww\aa-\ww}{1+\aa+\ww},
$$
we can show
$$
\w( a - 1)(1+\aa+\ww)-\ww(\aa-1)(1+a+\w)=0. \tag{1}
$$
Using $\w\ww=1$, $a\aa=1$, after expanding, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
&\quad \w( a - 1)(1+\aa+\ww)-\ww(\aa-1)(1+a+\w) \\
&= \w(a-1)(1+\aa)+(a-1) - \ww(\aa-1)(1+a)-(\aa-1) \\
&= \w(a-\aa)-\ww(\aa-a)+(a-\aa) \\
&= (\w+\ww+1)(a-\aa).
\end{align*}
$$
Note that $\w+\ww=-1$, so $(1)$ is proved.